# Low severity when installing Dropone in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone

Whenever I want to install Dropzone in Laravel I add the following line in my terminal

```
npm i dropzone --save-dev
```

but then the following error shows and Dropzone doesn't fully install

```
+ dropzone@5.7.2
updated 1 package and audited 1091 packages in 42.828s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Then when I type the following in my terminal to check what is the vulnerability

```
npm audit fix
```

The following appears

```
up to date in 9.494s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 1097 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

So I type the following

```
npm audit
```

Then the following appears

```
                       === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         yargs-parser

  Patched in      >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2

  Dependency of   laravel-mix [dev]

  Path            laravel-mix > yargs > yargs-parser

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500

found 1 low severity vulnerability in 1097 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

So can anyone help me fix this vulnerability?

Comment: Just because some packages may have vulnerabilities, does not mean they did not get installed. The packages installed just fine.

Comment: @Celsiuss

I checked what the error was, and I got this output

`npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
`

Comment: That is not errors. It is just informing you that some dependencies which are platform dependent, are not being installed. Which is intentional

Comment: @Celsiuss Oh ok, Thank you so much!